# HikariCPとOracleDBによるConnectionPoolの枯渇

Tags: spring, oracle

Spring Bootによるシステムを構築しています。
HikariCPを使用してOracleDBと接続を行っています。

起動時は問題ないのですが、稼働後しばらくすると確保していたConnection Poolが一つもなくなり、Total Connection が0になります。
そうなった場合、アプリケーションを再起動するまでConnectionが戻ることがありません。
何が原因として考えられますでしょうか。

HikariPoolの設定は以下のようにしています。

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
```

一度Connection-timeoutのせいだと考えたため、これを3600000（1時間)に変更したところ、
ログに以下のように表示され、同じように枯渇現象が発生していたため、60000と縮めました。

```
(IOエラー: Invalid Operation, NOT Connected). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

しばらく安定稼働していたのですが、ある時からまた同様の現象が発生するようになりました。

Comment: 「Connection Poolが一つもなくなり、Total Connection が0になります。」これは何を見て分かったことですか？

Comment: Jconsoleにて確認しました。

Comment: Jconsoleのどの部分を確認されたのでしょうか？

Comment: MBeans>com.zaxxer.hikari>Pool>属性の項目に表示されるTotalConnections、IdleConnections、ActiveConnectionsを確認したところ、TotalConnectionsが0になっていました。

Comment: うーん、見ているところは間違ってなさそうですね。`TotalConnections`=`IdleConnections`+`ActiveConnections`が成立するんじゃないかと思いますが、`TotalConnections`=0の状態のときは`IdleConnections`も`ActiveConnections`も0になってますかね？

Comment: はい、全て0になっています。

Comment: うーん、不良コネクションが溜まってしまってるのかもしれないですね。`logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG`と`logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG`を`application.properties`に追加して、Hikari CPのログを詳細化してみると、何か分かるのではないかと思います。

Comment: すみません、現象際現に時間がかかってしまい、報告が遅れました。
結論から申しますと、再現してログ出力もありましたが、原因がわかりません。
maxlifetimeに到達したコネクションからClosing connectionして、Add connectionをしますが、あるタイミングからCloseの処理しか出力されなくなります。

Comment: コネクションを追加しない理由がログに出ていると思うんですけどね。うーん、ログを見てみたい。あとは`spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime`をコメントアウトしているとか、`connection-test-query: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`を追加してみるとか、で動きは変わりませんかね？本番環境だと難しいかもしれませんが。

Comment: ログには本当にcloserとadderのログしか出ていません。
本日再現したので再度調査してみました。
その際オラクルのListnerログを確認したのですが、アプリケーションログがCloserのログを出力したタイミングで、オラクルのListenerログにアプリケーションにコネクションを貼りにいっているログがあるのですが、アプリケーション側でAdderのログがなく、そこから再度接続できていないようです。

Comment: `connection-test-query`は入れてみました？

Comment: 入れていません。別サイトでconnection-test-queryはJDBC4準拠のドライバ使用時は推奨しないと記載があったので、本番環境には組み込めていません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hikari CPのGitHubのissuesに[同様の事象](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1256)が報告されていました。このページをじっくり読んでいただければ、本件も解決するのではないかと思います。

ざっと読んだ印象ですが、おそらく、[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822552/setting-network-timeout-for-jdbc-connection/18824038#18824038)を参考にソケットタイムアウトを設定すれば、解決するのではないかと推測します。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
確認したところ、確かに同様の事例に見受けられます。ご教示頂いた箇所を参考に設定を施し、様子を見てみたいと思います。

Comment: 案内頂いたサイトを参考に、
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5000
をapplication.propertiesに追加してみましたが、年明けに現象が再発していました。
再度サイトの内容確認してみますが、他に確認すべき箇所があればご教示いただければと思います。

Comment: 状況が状況なので、非推奨でも`connection-test-query`を入れてみてもいいかもしれませんね。あとは事象前後のスレッドダンプを取得してみるとか。

Comment: 検証に時間がかかってしまいましたが、結論からすると、おそらく解決してそうです。案内頂いたサイトをもう一度読み返し、CONNECT_TIMEOUTだけでなく、spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=5000も追加したところ、2週間以上ハングアップせずに動いてます。恐らく問題ありません。

Comment: お、そうですか！それはよかったです。`ReadTimeout`も気にはなっていましたが、事象から考えて、`CONNECT_TIMEOUT`で解決する可能性が高いと判断しました。この件ちょっと気になっていたので、メッセージいただけてすっきりしました。

Comment: 丁寧にご教授いただきありがとうございました。大変助かりました！ログにはたまにsocketTimeoutのログが出力されるようになりましたので、ReadTimeoutが効いた結果なのかなと思います。（細かい動きまではよくわかってませんが;)